# How to format number as currency in array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, formatting, money-format

Im having trouble with this code - getting a 500 error, I need to format as currency for the values in an array. But getting stuck:

If I use round() - it will work - but it just rounds the number, which is not what Im after.

```
$cart[] = array('name' => $message->name, 'values' => array(round($delivery->revenue), $delivery->uniqConversions));
```

But if I try to use money_format, it does not work:

```
$cart[] = array('name' => $message->name, 'values' => array(money_format('$%i', ($delivery->revenue), $delivery->uniqConversions));
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are missing `)` at the end of your line:

```
$cart[] = array('name' => $message->name, 'values' => array(money_format('$%i', ($delivery->revenue), $delivery->uniqConversions)));
```

Thats why you are getting Error 500.